# Getting conversion issue after migrating jackson-databind from 2.11.4 to 2.12.13.2

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

We have recently migrated  jackson-databind from 3.11.4 to 3.12.13.2 version and springframework from 5.2.19.RELEASE to 5.2.22.RELEASE. after the migration we see below exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (

To fix the issue i have added below code

mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

which fixed the issue, but i see conversation error now INSTANT type conversation.

expected is "myTime":{"epochSecond":1627413300,"nano":0}

but it is coming as "myTime":1.6274133E9

error : Reason is: Expected a OBJECT, instead got NUMBER for key myTime

---

**working code with older version**

**pom dependencies -**

jackson-databind - 2.11.4
jackson-datatype-jsr310 - 2.11.4

**sample code**

```
public class ObjectMapperTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     try{
            ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
        
           
           Message message = new Message();
           System.out.println(message);
           String s2= o.writeValueAsString(message);
           System.out.println(s2);
         JsonNode i3=   o.readTree(s2);
           System.out.println(i3);
           
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 static class Message
 { 
     private String source;
     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, timezone = "UTC")
     private Instant timestamp = Instant.now();
     
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message [source=" + source + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + "]";
    }
 }
```

}

**output**

```
  Message [source=null, timestamp=2022-05-06T12:28:49.004Z]
  {"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}
  {"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}
```

**Sample code after version upgrade**

**pom depedencies**

jackson-databind - 2.13.2.1
jackson-datatype-jsr310 - 2.13.2

**code changes**

just add below lines to the above code

```
          ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
          o.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

**output**

```
  Message [source=null, timestamp=2022-05-06T12:28:49.004Z]
  {"timestamp":1651839918.691000000}
  {"timestamp":1.651839918691E9}
```

**Expected output**

```
  Message [source=null, timestamp=2022-05-06T12:28:49.004Z]
  {"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}
  {"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}
```

Comment: Check your dependency tree whether jackson-datatype-jsr310 is available.

Comment: i see jackson-datatype-jsr310 is already part my pom through transitive dependency

Comment: Can you add error reproducible code? Your pom, Dto etc .

Comment: Working code with older version

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.4</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>

Comment: try{
          ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
      
         
         Message message = new Message();
         System.out.println(message);
         String s2= o.writeValueAsString(message);
         System.out.println(s2);
       JsonNode i3=   o.readTree(s2);
         System.out.println(i3);
         
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 static class Message
  { 
      private String source;
      @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, timezone = "UTC")
      private Instant timestamp = Instant.now();

Comment: output
Message [source=null, timestamp=2022-05-06T12:28:49.004Z]
{"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}
{"timestamp":{"epochSecond":1651840129,"nano":4000000}}

Comment: <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.2</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>


just added     o.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); 
output :
Message [source=null, timestamp=2022-05-06T12:25:18.691Z]
{"timestamp":1651839918.691000000}
{"timestamp":1.651839918691E9}

Comment: unable to share the whole code on one comment..please let me if i can share via email

Comment: Put it in the question, not the comments...

Comment: Hi Sibin & Ryan,
I have updated the question. please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by creating a custom instant serializer and registering it with JavaTimeModule

public class EpochSecondInstantSerializer extends JsonSerializer {

```
@Override
public Class<Instant> handledType() {
    return Instant.class;
}

@Override
public void serialize(Instant instant, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("epochSecond", instant.getEpochSecond());
    jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("nano", instant.getNano());
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

then registering with JavaTimeModule
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(
new JavaTimeModule().addSerializer(new EpochSecondInstantSerializer()));